# Magento - Add sub blocks

Tags: php, magento, layout, magento-1.7

Magento - Add custom block
I am trying insert child block with many of options, but anyway it shows only non-readable symbols. What is it? Someone has seen something like that?
[image: non-readable symbols]

I don't understand what happens and why it happens.

Option 1 in template file

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template','template_name')->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml'))->toHtml();
```

Option 2 in the layout

```
<block type="module/block" name="view" template="path/to/template.phtml">
    <block type="module/block_question" name="view_question" as="question" template="path/to/subtemplate.phtml"/>
</block>
```

And in the template `path/to/template.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('question'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you wanted to output a block before the totals block on the cart details page, you could do the following in your extension's layout.xml

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="myextension/block" name="myextension.block" as="myextension_block" template="myextension/template.phtml">
            <action method="setChild"><name>totals</name><block>totals</block></action>
        </block>
        <action method="setChild"><name>totals</name><block>myextension.block</block></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

And in your template.phtml file you would have:

```
<div id="myextension">
    // Your template code
</div>

// Render the totals block that you placed inside your block
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
```

let me know if i can help you more.

or try below

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘core/template’)->setTemplate(‘templateFolder/yourtemplate.phtml’)->toHtml(); ?>
```

or with running code like

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('goodtest/test.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use to create a static block.

Then, add this code to poll.xml:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_yourblocknamehere">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>yourblocknamehere</block_id></action>
</block>
```

poll.xml directory

```
/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout
```

Comment: I know how to add static block, I want to add my custom block or core/template but it provide to error above.

Answer (score -1):

I think the template file use a different ENCoding or file format, and the method to load template is correct, but issue is related to file content.